# Cannot see recording red button for XCUITest in Xcode 9.2

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcuitest

As I am new to `XCUITest`, I want to write a test case by recording actions in the simulator but can't see the recording button in `XCTestCase` class.

What is the process to record a test case?

Answer (score 3):

This might seem trivial, but almost drove me mad when I started with XCUITesting:

Notice that your cursor must be inside a function starting with `test`:

[image: Test can be recorded]

This won't work, though (Record button is greyed out):

[image: Test won't work because of cursor position]

Answer (score 2):

I think that if you are not seeing the record button is because you don't have a `iOS UI Testing Bundle` in your targets. To do this you need to go to your project file and click the "+" button down on targets and then you add an `iOS UI Testing Bundle`. Then you will see a new folder named as your new target. There you can add UI tests and record them.

Comment: Also I highly recommend you to  take a look to the [UI Testing in Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/406/) video presentation. It will clearly explain you how to record UITesting With XCUITest and also will explain you the basics and the core clases (`XCUIAplication`,`XCUIElement`,`XCUIElementQuery`) of the framework.